# list out most matching ids first, others later

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently developing a "different" style of search. I have following table

```
id     keywords
1      apple orange mango grapes watermelon
2      apple mango
3      orange
4      orange grapes apple
5      grapes
6      grapes mango apple
7      watermelon apple orange
```

and my search field is a text-box where ore or more fruit names can be mentioned, for example

```
 apple grapes
```

I need results in following manner: first I will search for first fruit (apple) in above table, so matching ids will be

```
 1, 2, 4, 6, 7
```

then I will search for second fruit (grapes) in above table, so matching ids will be

```
 1, 4, 5, 6
```

As you can see above, apple and grapes appeared at following ids

```
 1, 4, 6
```

I need a query which shell give me most matching IDs first, then other later

```
 1, 4, 6, 2, 7, 5
```

Comment: How it store in table comma separated or by space and how to give search parameter?

Comment: How are you trying to achieve it? Post your query too. It will help others to answer it better.

Comment: `Textbox` from `html` `form`? `C#`? `VB.net`? and then pass to `SQL` string?

Comment: I don't see any code that we can review nor any statement that describes the problem with the code. Are you simply wanting us to create the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing the parsing in php for each word, you can try:

```
select k.*
from table k
order by (find_in_set($keyword1, replace(keywords, ' ', ',')) > 0 +
          find_in_set($keyword2, replace(keywords, ' ', ',')) > 0 +
          find_in_set($keyword3, replace(keywords, ' ', ',')) > 0
         ) desc;
```

However, you should not be storing the data in a list (space delimited or comma delimited).  Instead, you should have a junction table with one row per id and keyword.